# How to Make a form snap to edges of the screen

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I just recently started learning Firemonkey, so if the question is stupid, please do not kick. How can I make a Firemonkey form that sticks to the edges of the screen. In VCL is easily done by using the properties ScreenSnap: = true and SnapBuffer: = 15 for example. Another way - processing messages WM_WWINDOWPOSCHANGING or WM_MOVING. How can I make the same with FireMonkey?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since FMX is platform neutral, doing platform specific things is a lot harder. It should become a little easier with FM2 that ships with Delphi XE3 now.

For Delphi XE2, probably the easiest way is to wrap your FMX stuff in a VCL form.